# Firebase Java SDK doesn't persist data and doesn't trigger callback. Tasks seems never complete

Tags: java, scala, firebase

I'm trying to write some data on Firebase based on this guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start and using Play Framework + Scala.

After call DatabaseReference.setValue nothing happens: The data isn't persisted on Firebase and my callback is not triggered.

Here's the code:

```
  lazy val conf = ConfigFactory.load()

  lazy val options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                                        .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(new FileInputStream(conf.getString("firebase.credentials.path"))))
                                        .setDatabaseUrl("https://orsz-xxxxx-xxxxx.firebaseio.com/")
                                        .build()

  lazy val propsDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()

  /** Initialize block to instantiates FirebaseApp **/
  {
    println("[FirebasePersistence] - Initialize FirebaseApp")
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG)
    println("[FirebasePersistence] - Initialize FirebaseApp Done!")
  }

  def persistProposition(prop: Proposition): Future[Proposition] = Future {
    val task = propsDB.setValue(1, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
      override def onComplete(databaseError: DatabaseError, databaseReference: DatabaseReference) {
        if (databaseError != null) {
          println("Error: " + databaseError.getMessage)
        } else {
          println("[FirebasePersistence.persistProposition] - OK")
        }
      }
    })
    prop
  }
```

I can see, testing on SBT console, that the task generated on setValue never completes even after seconds:

```
scala> task.isComplete
 res6: Boolean = false
```

Executing with Firebase log level DEBUG I get this log:

```
Thu Apr 06 08:53:37 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
Thu Apr 06 08:53:37 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] RepoOperation: set: /
Thu Apr 06 08:53:37 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] DataOperation: set: / 1
Thu Apr 06 08:53:37 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] RepoOperation: Aborting transactions for path: /. Affected: /
Thu Apr 06 08:53:38 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Successfully fetched token, opening connection
Thu Apr 06 08:53:38 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] Connection: conn_0 - Opening a connection
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] WebSocket: ws_0 - websocket opened
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] WebSocket: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] WebSocket: ws_0 - ws message: {"t":"c","d":{"t":"h","d":{"ts":1491479619239,"v":"5","h":"s-usc1c-nss-135.firebaseio.com","s":"bxE2HQCxtNNs4EznaO5xjWsInnIpu5Fi"}}}
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] WebSocket: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44991
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] WebSocket: ws_0 - HandleNewFrameCount: 1
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] WebSocket: ws_0 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {t=c, d={t=h, d={h=s-usc1c-nss-135.firebaseio.com, s=bxE2HQCxtNNs4EznaO5xjWsInnIpu5Fi, v=5, ts=1491479619239}}}
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] Connection: conn_0 - Got control message: {t=h, d={h=s-usc1c-nss-135.firebaseio.com, s=bxE2HQCxtNNs4EznaO5xjWsInnIpu5Fi, v=5, ts=1491479619239}}
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] Connection: conn_0 - realtime connection established
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] PersistentConnection: pc_0 - onReady
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] PersistentConnection: pc_0 - handling timestamp
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Sending first connection stats
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] Connection: conn_0 - Sending data: {t=d, d={a=s, r=0, b={c={sdk.java.3-0-0=1}}}}
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] WebSocket: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44993
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] PersistentConnection: pc_0 - calling restore state
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Restoring auth.
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] Connection: conn_0 - Sending data (contents hidden)
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] WebSocket: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44996
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] WebSocket: ws_0 - ws message: {"t":"d","d":{"r":0,"b":{"s":"ok","d":""}}}
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] WebSocket: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44836
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] WebSocket: ws_0 - HandleNewFrameCount: 1
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] WebSocket: ws_0 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {t=d, d={r=0, b={d=, s=ok}}}
Thu Apr 06 08:53:39 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] Connection: conn_0 - received data message: {r=0, b={d=, s=ok}}
Thu Apr 06 08:53:40 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] WebSocket: ws_0 - ws message: {"t":"d","d":{"r":1,"b":{"s":"permission_denied","d":"Access denied."}}}
Thu Apr 06 08:53:40 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] WebSocket: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 43628
Thu Apr 06 08:53:40 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] WebSocket: ws_0 - HandleNewFrameCount: 1
Thu Apr 06 08:53:40 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] WebSocket: ws_0 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {t=d, d={r=1, b={d=Access denied., s=permission_denied}}}
Thu Apr 06 08:53:40 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] Connection: conn_0 - received data message: {r=1, b={d=Access denied., s=permission_denied}}
Thu Apr 06 08:53:40 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Authentication failed: permission_denied (Access denied.)
Thu Apr 06 08:53:40 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] Connection: conn_0 - closing realtime connection
Thu Apr 06 08:53:40 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] WebSocket: ws_0 - websocket is being closed
Thu Apr 06 08:53:40 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Got on disconnect due to OTHER
Thu Apr 06 08:53:40 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
Thu Apr 06 08:53:40 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] ConnectionRetryHelper: Scheduling retry in 821ms
Thu Apr 06 08:53:41 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] WebSocket: ws_0 - closed
Thu Apr 06 08:53:41 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
Thu Apr 06 08:53:41 BRT 2017 [DEBUG] PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Successfully fetched token, opening connection
```

I can see some Permission Denied on log but can't figure out why.

I already test the credentials on FileInputStream and it is OK.

The permission on Firebase project:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

I already test using firebase-admin-4.1.6 and firebase-server-sdk-3.0.1 and have the same result

EDIT: 
I printed the FirebaseApp, FirebaseDatabase and DatabaseReference objets before call setValue and got the lines above.
How may I ensure that admin sdk is initialized correctly?

```
FirebaseApp=FirebaseApp{name=[DEFAULT], options=FirebaseOptions{databaseUrl=https://orsz-xxxxx-xxxxx.firebaseio.com/, credential=com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseCredentials$CertCredential@558b77e8, databaseAuthVariableOverride={}}}
FirebaseApp.name=[DEFAULT]

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()=com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase@124cb42b

DatabaseReference=https://orsz-xxxxx-xxxxx.firebaseio.com/12345
```

Comment: See my follow up below. Not really an answer, but way too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested with a new project and Admin SDK version 4.1.6.

With this Java code:

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("43256111");
ref.setValue(1, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        if (databaseError != null) {
            System.err.println(databaseError);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Written");
        }
    }
});
```

*The `43256111` is the location in my database that I used for testing.*

I get this after a few seconds:

> Written

The rules don't even matter in this case, since the Admin SDK runs with administrative privileges it by-passes even these rules for me:

```
"43256111": {
  ".write": false
}
```

So I'm not sure what's going on in your case, but I can't reproduce it. Are you sure you have the admin SDK initialized correctly?

Comment: I edit my question with some informations about "How may I ensure that admin sdk is initialized correctly?"